# How to remove ' from the beginning of dictionary?

Tags: python, json

How to convert this below string to Python dictionary?

```
import json

nls_wti = '"{"dataset": "nls","nls_tables_wti":[{ "source":"l_history" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM l_trans_history a WHERE CAST(a.transaction_date AS DATE) = " ,"pathb":" ) UNION SELECT a. FROM loanacct_trans_history a INNER JOIN ( SELECT reversal_transrefno from loanacct_trans_history WHERE (transaction_code % 2) = 1 and CAST(transaction_date AS DATE) >= " ,"pathc":" and transrefno <> 0 ) b ON a.transrefno = b.reversal_transrefno --" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_loanacct_trans_history" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"b" } ,{ "source":"loanacct_payment_history" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM l_history a WHERE CAST(a.gl_date AS DATE) = " ,"pathb":" ) --" ,"pathc":"--" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_l_history" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"c" } ,{ "source":"loanacct_statistics" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM loanacct_statistics a WHERE a.master_record = 0 OR ( a.master_record = 1 and a.year_number = DATEPART(Year, " ,"pathb":" )) OR (a.master_record = 2 and a.month_number = CONVERT(INT,LEFT(REPLACE( " ,"pathc":" ,""-"","""") ,6)))) --" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_l_statistics" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"d"}]}"'
nls_wti = nls_wti.replace("'", "")
nls_wti = json.loads(nls_wti)
```

Expecting:

```
{"dataset": "nls","nls_tables_wti":[{ "source":"l_history" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM l_trans_history a WHERE CAST(a.transaction_date AS DATE) = " ,"pathb":" ) UNION SELECT a. FROM loanacct_trans_history a INNER JOIN ( SELECT reversal_transrefno from loanacct_trans_history WHERE (transaction_code % 2) = 1 and CAST(transaction_date AS DATE) >= " ,"pathc":" and transrefno <> 0 ) b ON a.transrefno = b.reversal_transrefno --" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_loanacct_trans_history" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"b" } ,{ "source":"loanacct_payment_history" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM l_history a WHERE CAST(a.gl_date AS DATE) = " ,"pathb":" ) --" ,"pathc":"--" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_l_history" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"c" } ,{ "source":"loanacct_statistics" ,"patha":" SELECT a. FROM loanacct_statistics a WHERE a.master_record = 0 OR ( a.master_record = 1 and a.year_number = DATEPART(Year, " ,"pathb":" )) OR (a.master_record = 2 and a.month_number = CONVERT(INT,LEFT(REPLACE( " ,"pathc":" ,""-"","""") ,6)))) --" ,"pathd":"--" ,"pathe":"--" ,"pathf":"--" ,"pathg":"--" ,"pathh":"--" ,"pathi":"--" ,"pathj":"--" ,"pathk":"--" ,"pathl":"t_l_statistics" ,"pathm":"WRITE_TRUNCATE" ,"pathn":"d"}]}
```

Above way it is not working or throwing error. If I can remove `'` from beginning it might solve the issue.

Comment: The leading and trailing ' makes nls_wti a string. You can't remove them because they won't appear in the string. What your expecting is not the expected structure of a dictionary. If you want that in .JSON file why don't you just write it to file?

Comment: That is not a proper JSON string with or without the `'` at the beginning and end... Try [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) on it.

Comment: The data not valid JSON. Among other issues, it contains a triple-quoted string — see `,"pathc":" ,""-"","""") ,6)))) --"` part.

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't the `'` quotes around the whole body, it's the extra `"` quotes. What you have is quoted twice; it should look like `'{"dataset": ...}'`, not `'"{"dataset": ...}"'`. Ideally, wherever `nls_wti` is coming from should send back proper JSON (if it's being read from a file, network request, or just copy-pasted in), but if you can't change that, you can remove the extra quotes with something like:

```py
nls_wti = nls_wti[1:-1]
```

which removes the first and last character of the text (those extra quotes).

Comment: That's not the only thing wrong. Did you try running your answer with the OP's data?

Comment: `nls_wti[1:-1]` is still not a proper JSON string. The quoted fields themselves are not correct.